# Iterating through a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

Would love some help on the following simple question. How can I iterate through a list of dictionaries? I would only need the keys of each dictionary. EG:

```
list_ = [{'negative': 'sad'}, {'negative': 'missed'},
         {'positive': 'already :D'},{'negative': 'cry'}, 
         {'negative': 'cheating'}, {'negative': 'worry'},
         {'positive': 'Chilling'},]
```

I would need to append the keys in the following list tweet_list

What is wrong with the following code? Apologies for the basic question, but it's mainly the data structure of the list_ that is causing me troubles.

EG:

```
for key in list_():
    append.tweet_list(key[0])
    print(tweet_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this list comprehension:

```
>>> [list(d.keys())[0] for d in list_]
['negative', 'negative', 'positive', 'negative', 'negative', 'negative', 'positive']
```

Comment: `[key for d in list_ for key in d]` - this one is better. On your suggestion - timeit.timeit = 6.885658357000011. On mine = 2.3229932919998646

Answer (score 3):

Note the different options in Python 2 and 3:

**Code**

```
[d.keys()[0] for d in list_]                               # python 2

[next(iter(d.viewkeys())) for d in list_]                  # python 2

[next(iter(d.keys())) for d in list_]                      # python 2/3

[k for d in list_ for k in d]                              # python 2/3
```

The middle options leverage [dictionary views](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) as opposed to lists.  The last option is most Pythonic (suggested by @Yaroslav Surzhikov).

---

**Timings**

Confirmed in Python 3 (wherever possible) via `%timeit -n 100000`:

1. 6.58 µs: `[list(d.keys())[0] for d in list_]`
2. 3.23 µs: `[d.keys()[0] for d in list_]`
3. 3.97 µs: `[next(iter(d.viewkeys())) for d in list_]`
4. 4.52 µs: `[next(iter(d.keys())) for d in list_]`
5. 1.75 µs: `[key for d in list_ for key in d]`

Contribution by @Yaroslav Surzhikov

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. If you want to retrieve the values instead of keys then use this.  `[key for d in list_ for key in d.values()]`